# Unequal to equal dimensions for a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to implement a custom formula for generating an equal size matrix (with custom number of rows and columns), based on certain math formula. I stuck on storing the values from an unequal size matrix to my output matrix, that needs to be of equal dimensions (3x3, 5x5, 9x9, etc).

This is the code:

```
def mex3():
    print "Say input size (d)"
    d = int(raw_input("> "))
    h = np.empty([d,d], dtype=np.float)
    global lx
    global ly
    global x
    global y
    lx_list = []
    ly_list = []
    x_list = []
    y_list = []
    value = []
    b = np.array([0, 0], dtype=np.float)
    a = 1
    for line in range(h.shape[0]):
        for col in range(h.shape[1]):
            lx = col - (d - 1)/2
            ly = (d - 1)/2 - line
            lx_list.append(lx)
            ly_list.append(ly)

    lam = np.column_stack((lx_list, ly_list))
    for i in lx_list:
        val = i - b[0]
        x_list.append(val)
    for j in ly_list:
        val = j - b[1]
        y_list.append(val)
    xy = np.column_stack((lx_list, ly_list))

    #This is the part that doesn't work
    for line in range(h.shape[0]):
        for col in range(h.shape[1]):
            for i in xy[0]:
                for j in xy[1]:
                    val = 0
                    val = (1 - i**2 - j**2) * math.exp(-((i**2)+(j**2))/2)
                    h[line, col] = val
    return h
```

My h matrix output only stores the last value in the 'val' variable, and not the corresponding values from xy matrix.
Edit: For example:
Say my xy matrix has is of this form:

```
[[-1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [-1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [-1. -1.]
 [ 0. -1.]
 [ 1. -1.]]
```

The corresponding h matrix should be like:

```
[[-1.,1.     0.,1.    1.,1.]
 [-1.,0.,    0.,0.,   1.,0.]
 [-1.,-1.,   0.,-1.,  1., -1.]
```

But note, that i need the resulted value stored, from the 'val' variable and not the -1,1 pair.
So the output should be like:

```
[[-0.36787944  0.         -0.36787944]
 [ 0.          1.          0.        ]
 [-0.36787944  0.         -0.36787944]]
```

Following the answer, I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
global i, j
    for line in range(h.shape[0]):
        for col in range(h.shape[1]):
            i = 0
            j = 0
            for i in xy[0]:
               for j in xy[1]:
                    val = (1 - i**2 - j**2) * math.exp(-((i**2)+(j**2))/2)
                    h[line, col] = val
                    i += 1
                    j += 1
```

Comment: how are you mapping the values from xy matrix to h matrix? Can show you examples of xy matrix and what h should look like based on that xy matrix?

Comment: I edited my main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current issue would be clear if you take a closer look at your loop -

```
#This is the part that doesn't work
for line in range(h.shape[0]):
    for col in range(h.shape[1]):
        for i in xy[0]:
            for j in xy[1]:
```

The above actually completely loops through `xy[0]` and `xy[1]` , calculating each for each `i,j` the value according to your formula and then setting it to `h[line, col]` . That is why for each element in `h` it has the last val calculated only, since the previous `val`s get overwritten as you are doing all this in a nested loop.

What you want would be to move i,j outside the loop completely, and increment them for each iteration of loop -

```
for line in range(h.shape[0]):
    for col in range(h.shape[1]):
```

Example Code -

```
i = 0
for line in range(h.shape[0]):
    for col in range(h.shape[1]):
        val = (1 - xy[i][0]**2 - xy[i][1]**2) * math.exp(-((xy[i][0]**2)+(xy[i][1]**2))/2)
        h[line, col] = val
        i += 1
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with the latest code.

Comment: Use the exact latest code I gave, you are still having nested loops, that would not work as i already explained